# Symfony 2 Twig form functions not available

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am creating a new Twig Environment object inside a custom class, that class is being rendered from an existing twig file. I am trying to render a form in my twig file which is being rendered from my custom class, however in this new Twig_Environment object form functions are not available, i have tried adding existing form extension from symfony's own twig object to my new twig object, that is not working either.

```
$path = 'some/directory'; // just simplifying here

$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem( $path );
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
     'cache' => __DIR__.'/../../../../../../app/cache/',
));
$tmpl = $twig->loadTemplate('EmailUs.html.twig');
$twig->addExtension( new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension( $this->pageObj->getContainer()->get('twig.form.renderer') ) );
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($tmpl);
return $response;
```

The error i get is

> "The function "form_start" does not exist in EmailUs.html.twig at line
>   8"

I was using symfony's own twig object to render the response but that was giving me the same error. Can you help pls? I am using Symfony 2.3.4

Form functions are available if i render a normal controller, they dont work fine if i create a custom twig object.

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using? `form_start` was introduced in [Symfony2.3](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/twig_reference.html).

Comment: hi i am using symfony 2.3.4, form_start works fine if i render a controller action, but it does not work if i create a custom twig object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it this way:

```
$loader = $pageFunctions->getContainer()->get('twig.loader');
$loader->addPath( $path );
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => __DIR__.'/../../../../../../app/cache/myTwig',
));  

foreach( $this->twig->getExtensions() as $ext ) {
    $twig->addExtension( $ext );
}

$tmpl = $twig->loadTemplate('EmailUs.html.twig');        

$rendered = $tmpl->display( array('control' => $this,
       'functions' => $pageFunctions,
       'params' => $params,
       'email_form'=>$form->createView() ) );

return $rendered;
```

Comment: Here you've done exactly what I suggested, why didn't you accept my answer? The problem was about `addExtension` and `loadTemplate` execution order.

Comment: no, not just that, i am using symfony's loader, adding ALL extensions from existing twig object, changing the cache path etc, despite i had solved the problem before looking at your answer, i can accept yours if you want, no big deal but that did solve my problem.

Comment: also did you render a form in your twig file? that was the main reason i did all this.

Comment: Well, now you are in practice duplicating the original twig object, retrieving the default loader from the container and re-binding all the extensions from `$this->twig` (which I assume is retrieved as `$container->get('twig')`). Why wouldn't you just use `$this->twig` instead?

Comment: because if i do that, i get the error that form_start is not available, i am rendering the template inside another template, i think twig only allows me to render a form a single template hierarchy or using the `render( controller() )` syntax, i am not duplicating every aspect of the original twig object, i am just adding the existing extensions and loader and hence avoid state of previous twig object. i hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ok. Wait a second: Where does `$form` and all the other vars come from?

Comment: i defined them in the code above it they are not included here

Answer (score 3):

Here's my working code (executed inside a controller action):

```
$path = __DIR__.'/../Resources/views/'; /* twig loader path */
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($path);
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension( new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension($this->get('twig.form.renderer')));
$tmpl = $twig->loadTemplate('test.html.twig');
return new Response($tmpl->render(array()));
```

I've mainly moved the `addExtension` call before the `loadTemplate` one (otherwise extensions would have been already initialized).

Comment: i need to render the template from outside of a controller action and this doesn't work either, it gives me errors about other resource files not being available.

Comment: My code totally works even inside a Command or anything else (as long as you can access the container in order to call `$container->get('twig.form.renderer')`). In your solution above you actually did what I suggested: moving the `addExtension` calls before the `loadTemplate` one!

Comment: i did that, but that alone did not do the trick, you see the problem i have is i am outside of the page controller, i am inside a custom twig file. i tried your code but that threw a exception, that i am missing some other twig files, the only thing similar is the addExtension call,

Comment: If my solution throws another exception, please tell me how you've used it and which other error you are having. It doesn't mean that my solution doesn't solve your original question.

Comment: used the same way you did, it said that symfony cant find a twig file which was coming from another bundle, that made me think that i need to use the symfony's original loader. And as i said i solved the problem before looking at your code, i started with doing the same thing you did, its that you tried it in a simpler context, mine isn't