# Symfony2 : render form as a string

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I am trying to render a form from a string in Symfony2 and get the result in a variable.
I tried this solution, [Symfony 2 Twig form functions not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311221/symfony-2-twig-form-functions-not-available) but I am getting an error (service 'twig.form.renderer' not avaliable). So I changed the addExtension part (not sure about the classes).
Here is my code :

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendererEngine = new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRendererEngine();
$env->addExtension(new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension(new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Form\TwigRenderer($rendererEngine)));
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->add('testField', 'text');
$form = $form->getForm()->createView();
return $env->render(
    '{{ form(form) }}',
    array('form' => $form)
);
```

Now I am getting "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException' with message 'No block "form" found while rendering the form"

Comment: Is it essential that you use a string rather that an template that just has `{{ form(form) }}` as it's contents?

Comment: I could use a template as well, but I think I would get the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I finally ended up using a much simpler approach, by defining a service :

    twig.stringloader:
        class: Twig_Loader_String
        tags:
            - { name: twig.loader }

and then

    echo $c->get('twig')->render('{{ form(form) }}', array('form' => $form));

Comment: Simpler than just using a template with the form block?

Answer (score 0):

You should include [form_div_layout](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) where `form` block is defined.

Answer (score 0):

For twig templation i use this code:

```
$twig = $this->container->get('twig');
$twig->initRuntime();

return JsonResponse::create(array(
    'success' => false,
    'form' => $twig->getExtension('form')->renderer->searchAndRenderBlock($form->createView(), 'widget'),
));
```

for php template engine:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.form')->widget($form->createView());
```

Comment: For symfony 3 it would be `getExtension('\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension')`